# Thermal reliefs or solid connection for high current PTH pads

Tags: pcb, thermal, high-current

I'm designing a BMS with up to 30 A, and I'm wondering about using thermal reliefs or solid connections for the PTH pad.
The pad is connected to two copper planes on the top and bottom layers.

[image]

Comment: You definitely don't thermal relief spokes on that.

Comment: i'm asking which is better, thermal reliefs or solid connection

Comment: How are you going to connect to that pad? Solder or a screw? Thermal pads are used so you can solder to the pad, otherwise the heat is conducted into the board and it is very difficult to get the pad hot enough to solder.

Comment: Better for what? Solid connection is better for high currents as you have uninterrupted copper. Best for soldering - thermal reliefs. Best for your situation?